# Discarding lists of same elements

Tags: programming-languages, python

Suppose, I have a list of lists where multiple lists can have same elements. In my final output, I just want one list with the same element. An example is the following:

**Input:** A=[[1,2,0], [0,1,2], [2,1,0], [4,5,6], [6,5,4]]

**Desired Output:** $[[0,1,2], [4,5,6]]$

Can someone help me with an easy function for doing so? Thank you so much.

Comment: What about [[1, 2], [2, 3]]?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please specify exactly what you want the output to be in general.  One example is not a substitute for a general problem specification.  "one list with the same element" is not clear.  Same as what?  You mention only one element, but the example shows multiple elements.

Comment: In fact, you are seeing your lists as (multi)sets.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an instance of the [set cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) problem.  There is no efficient algorithm, but you can read about standard algorithms.

Comment: It could be that, or it could just be removal of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Sort every sublist, then sort the main list with lexicographical ordering. The duplicates will appear next to each other.

$$[[1,2,0], [6,5,4], [0,1,2], [2,1,0], [4,5,6]]$$
then
$$[[0,1,2], [4,5,6], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [4,5,6]]$$
then
$$[[0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [4,5,6], [4,5,6]]$$